# Some faces are not reacting as expected to shading

Tags: mesh

I'm new to Blender and I've started learning how to create clothes for GTA V by converting Sims 4 CC into GTA V.

I sometimes have this problem where some faces don't react appropriately to the texture I applied. I've tried flipping the normals but it doesn't fix the problem. Any help?

[image]

Here's the file if needed: https://we.tl/t-Q6kHQhrKWu

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Just `tab` to go into *Edit Mode*, then select all with `a` then then press `m` to merge > *By Distance*. Then while all is still selected, press `Shift+Ctrl+N` to recalculate normals. Then while all is still selected, go to menu *Face > Tris to Quads*. Then add a Solidify Modifier so the mesh from the top that turns outward will not have "inverted" normals.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you so much!!